# Dialog+NLC+RR連携について

Tags: watson-api

やりたいことは、DialogからNLCをコールして、確信度低い場合、R&Rへ取り合わせをし、回答をDialogにて表示させる。

Dialogのxmlにて直接NLCをコールできることを試してできたが、どのようにすれば、R&RのAPIをコールできるかが分からないです。

お手数ですが、教えていただければ、助かります。